# Convert portions of json file to csv with pandas

Tags: json, pandas, csv, normalize

I have a JSON file from which I need to convert a particular array to CSV, and then include a value from outside the array as well. Here's my sample JSON:

```
{
    "activities" : [
        {
          "act_id" : "123456",
          "act_employee_logged" : {
            "emp_id" : "123",
            "emp_code" : "ABC123",
            "emp_name" : "First Last Name",
          },
          "act_type" : "ActivityType",
          "act_external_attendees" : [
            {
              "contact_id" : "Guest789",
              "contact_name" : "First Last Name",
              "contact_email" : "last.first@example.com",
              "contact_phone" : "2105555555"
            },
            {
              "contact_id" : "Guest790",
              "contact_name" : "First Last Name 1",
              "contact_email" : "last.first1@example.com",
              "contact_phone" : "2105555556"
            }
          ],
          "act_internal_attendees" : [
            {
              "att_id" : "123",
              "att_code" : "ABC123",
              "att_name" : "First Last Name",
              "att_email" : "last.first@example.com"
            },
            {
              "att_id" : "124",
              "att_code" : "ABC124",
              "att_name" : "First Last Name 1",
              "att_email" : "last.first1@example.com"
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to convert the act_external_attendees to a data frame and then CSV. I've successfully done that, and here's the portion of the code that reads the file and creates my data frame:

```
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd

    with open("/filepath/interaction_response.json") as f:      #####  
            d = json.load(f)
    
    ext_att = pd.json_normalize(data=d['activities'], record_path='act_external_attendees', meta=['contact_id', 'contact_name', 'contact_email', 'contact_phone'],errors='ignore',record_prefix = '_')
```

The part that's giving me a headache is that I need to include the `act_id` value as a column in each row of my data frame and CSV, and so far I haven't found a way to accomplish that. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

### Loading Libraries

```
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
```

### Reading file

```
with open("/filepath/interaction_response.json") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

### Creating auxiliary structure

```
my_list = []
for sublist in myj['activities']:
    act_id = sublist['act_id']
    for val in sublist['act_external_attendees']:
        val.update({'act_id': act_id})
        my_list.append(val)
```

The result would be

```
print(my_list)
[{'contact_id': 'Guest789', 'contact_name': 'First Last Name', 'contact_email': 'last.first@example.com', 'contact_phone': '2105555555', 'act_id': '123456'}, {'contact_id': 'Guest790', 'contact_name': 'First Last Name 1', 'contact_email': 'last.first1@example.com', 'contact_phone': '2105555556', 'act_id': '123456'}]
```

### Creating dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)

print(df)
  contact_id       contact_name            contact_email contact_phone  act_id
0   Guest789    First Last Name   last.first@example.com    2105555555  123456
1   Guest790  First Last Name 1  last.first1@example.com    2105555556  123456
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo. But your method returns the same results that I'm currently getting. I 'm able to get contact_id, contact_name, etc., but my problem is I need to also include act_id in each row. Act_id is outside of the act_external_attendees array.

Comment: Updated according to your comment.

Comment: Thanks Paulo. This was exactly what I was looking for. I'm still new with Python, so I'll study the solution and learn from it.  Thanks again!